# Error While Calling A Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

**What is wrong in this procedure?**

I have a `table` family:

```
Name          Null?    Type         
------------- -------- ------------ 
NAME          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25) 
NICK_NAME              VARCHAR2(15) 
GENDER        NOT NULL CHAR(1)      
AGE           NOT NULL NUMBER(3)    
MARITL_STATUS NOT NULL VARCHAR2(15) 
QUALIFICTN    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20) 
NO_OF_CHLDRN           NUMBER(2)
```

I have created a procedure to insert values in this table. The procedure is compiled and created successfully:

```
create or replace procedure "insert_family"    
(NAME varchar2 ,
NICK_NAME varchar2 ,
GENDER VARCHAR2,
AGE number,
MARITL_STAUS varchar2,
QUALIFICTN varchar2,
NO_OF_CHLDRN number)    
is    
begin    
insert into family values(NAME,NICK_NAME,GENDER,AGE,MARITL_STAUS,QUALIFICTN,NO_OF_CHLDRN);    
end;
```

But when I try to call this procedure through:

```
BEGIN
insert_family('AYUSH','SHUKLA','MALE',12,'UNMARRIED','SCHOOL',0);
END;
/
```

It gives me this error:

> BEGIN 
>   insert_family('AYUSH','SHUKLA','MALE',12,'UNMARRIED','SCHOOL',0); 
>   END; 
>   Error report - 
>   ORA-06550: line 2, column 1: 
>   PLS-00201: identifier 'INSERT_FAMILY' must be declared 
>   ORA-06550: line 2, column 1: 
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored 
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s" 
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error. 
>   *Action:

The problem seems to be in procedure as there is no parameter shown to
have values in debug mode:

[image: procedure_parameters]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an object in Oracle with double quotes, Oracle creates that objects with the same case as you entered it. Try dropping the "insert_family"   procedure and creating it without the double quotes.

This should help.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE family
  2       ( NAME          VARCHAR2(25),
  3         NICK_NAME     VARCHAR2(15),
  4         GENDER        CHAR(1),
  5         AGE           NUMBER(3),
  6         MARITL_STATUS VARCHAR2(15),
  7         QUALIFICTN    VARCHAR2(20),
  8         NO_OF_CHLDRN  NUMBER(2) );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace procedure "insert_family"
  2     ( NAME varchar2 ,
  3       NICK_NAME varchar2 ,
  4       GENDER VARCHAR2,
  5       AGE number,
  6       MARITL_STAUS varchar2,
  7       QUALIFICTN varchar2,
  8       NO_OF_CHLDRN number)
  9  is
 10  begin
 11  insert into family values(NAME,NICK_NAME,GENDER,AGE,MARITL_STAUS,QUALIFICTN,NO_OF_CHLDRN);
 12  end;
 13  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace procedure "Insert_family"
  2     ( NAME varchar2 ,
  3       NICK_NAME varchar2 ,
  4       GENDER VARCHAR2,
  5       AGE number,
  6       MARITL_STAUS varchar2,
  7       QUALIFICTN varchar2,
  8       NO_OF_CHLDRN number)
  9  is
 10  begin
 11  insert into family values(NAME,NICK_NAME,GENDER,AGE,MARITL_STAUS,QUALIFICTN,NO_OF_CHLDRN);
 12  end;
 13  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace procedure "iNsert_family"
  2     ( NAME varchar2 ,
  3       NICK_NAME varchar2 ,
  4       GENDER VARCHAR2,
  5       AGE number,
  6       MARITL_STAUS varchar2,
  7       QUALIFICTN varchar2,
  8       NO_OF_CHLDRN number)
  9  is
 10  begin
 11  insert into family values(NAME,NICK_NAME,GENDER,AGE,MARITL_STAUS,QUALIFICTN,NO_OF_CHLDRN);
 12  end;
 13  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace procedure "inSert_family"
  2     ( NAME varchar2 ,
  3       NICK_NAME varchar2 ,
  4       GENDER VARCHAR2,
  5       AGE number,
  6       MARITL_STAUS varchar2,
  7       QUALIFICTN varchar2,
  8       NO_OF_CHLDRN number)
  9  is
 10  begin
 11  insert into family values(NAME,NICK_NAME,GENDER,AGE,MARITL_STAUS,QUALIFICTN,NO_OF_CHLDRN);
 12  end;
 13  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> exec insert_family('AYUSH','SHUKLA','MALE',12,'UNMARRIED','SCHOOL',0);
BEGIN insert_family('AYUSH','SHUKLA','MALE',12,'UNMARRIED','SCHOOL',0); END;

      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'INSERT_FAMILY' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored


SQL> select object_name, object_type, status from user_objects where upper(object_name)=upper('inSert_family') order by 1;

OBJECT_NAME                    OBJECT_TYPE          STATUS
------------------------------ -------------------- ------------
Insert_family                  PROCEDURE            VALID
iNsert_family                  PROCEDURE            VALID
inSert_family                  PROCEDURE            VALID
insert_family                  PROCEDURE            VALID

4 rows selected.
```

Comment: Although it did work !! But I am still in doubt as :

`create or replace procedure "INSERTUSER"    
(id IN NUMBER,    
name IN VARCHAR2)    
is    
begin    
insert into user1 values(id,name);    
end;`

is working fine with :

`BEGIN    
   insertuser(101,'Rahul');  
END;`    
/

Comment: You could also call the procedure with double quotes.  eg  `"insert_family"`

Comment: You need to avoid using double quotes when you create objects. Then everything will be created as upper case.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it should work irregardless of case-sensitivity.

It appears to be a bug in SQL*Developer.

The SQL Statement SQL*Developer uses is:

```
SELECT
  position, argument_name, data_level
 ,data_type, in_out,
  CASE
      WHEN char_used = 'C' THEN char_length
      ELSE data_length
    END data_length
 ,data_precision, data_scale
 ,type_owner, type_name, type_subname
 ,pls_type
FROM sys.dba_arguments
WHERE
      owner         =:owner
  AND object_id     =:id
  AND object_name   =:name
  AND nvl( overload,'0' ) = :overload
ORDER BY sequence;
```

The value for the BIND variable `"NAME"` is `"INSERT_FAMILY"` instead of `"insert_family"`.

Object names without double-quotes are case insensitive.

With double-quotes, object names are case sensitive and you can have spaces (and other non-standard characters) in the name.

The search above is doing a case-sensitive search.  The value has been `UPPER()`.  Since you defined the procedure as lower-case using double-quotes, there are no parameters.

Comment: "Technically, it should work irregardless of case-sensitivity." It is not a bug with SQL Developer. sqlplus will yield the same results. It is a "feature" with Oracle.